# i need help scraping the following information from the webpage

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i need to obtain details of federal agencies from a web page that lists the pages alphabetically a-w. I need to get the agency name,website and contact

the code that i have only returns the agency name from one page.

```
import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> res = requests.get("https://www.usa.gov/federal-agencies/")
>>> soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
>>> soup.select('.url')
for i in soup.select('.url'):
    print(i.text)
```

### i expect to get; the Agency name, website and contact address for all the pages,from a to page w

Comment: Your code will only return the agency name because you're iterating over every element with the `.url` class, have you actually tried to get the rest of the data that you're after? If so, please post what you have and what's going wrong.

Comment: You need to use https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io, because you have to click buttons and links.

Comment: i need help to get the rest of the details from href tag. please help me  using requests and beautiful soup and any other additional library.

Comment: Selenium is not needed as each page has a specified link to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to iterate through each page, and follow the link of each item to then pull the data you want:

**Code:**

```
import requests
import bs4

for letter in map(chr, range(97, 123)):
    res = requests.get("https://www.usa.gov/federal-agencies/%s" %letter)
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

    section = soup.find('ul', {'class':'one_column_bullet'})
    links = [ 'https://www.usa.gov' + i['href'] for i in section.find_all('a', {'class':'url'})]
    for link in links:
        res2 = requests.get(link)
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text,'lxml')

        agency_name = soup.find('h1').text
        website = soup.find('h3',{'class':'org'}).findNext('a')['href']

        try:
            address = soup.find('p',{'class':'spk street-address'}).text.strip()
            address = address.split('\n')
            address = ' '.join([ i.strip() for i in address if i.strip() != '' ])
        except:
            address = 'N/A'

        print('Name:\t\t%s\nWebsite:\t%s\nAddress:\t%s\n' %(agency_name, website, address))
```

**Output:**

```
Name:           U.S. AbilityOne Commission
Website:        http://www.abilityone.gov
Address:        1401 S. Clark Street Suite 715 Arlington, VA 22202-3259

Name:           U.S. Access Board
Website:        http://www.access-board.gov/
Address:        1331 F St., NW Suite 1000 Washington, DC 20004-1111

Name:           Administration for Children and Families
Website:        http://www.acf.hhs.gov/
Address:        330 C St., SW Washington, DC 20201

Name:           Administration for Community Living
Website:        http://www.acl.gov
Address:        One Massachusetts Ave., NW Washington, DC 20201

Name:           Administration for Native Americans
Website:        http://www.acf.hhs.gov/programs/ana/
Address:        2nd Floor, West Aerospace Center 370 L'Enfant Promenade, SW Washington, DC 20447-0002

Name:           Administrative Conference of the United States
Website:        http://acus.gov/
Address:        1120 20th St., NW Suite 706 South Washington, DC 20036

Name:           Administrative Office of the U.S. Courts
Website:        http://www.uscourts.gov/
Address:        One Columbus Circle, NE Washington, DC 20544

...
```

Comment: hello,chitown88, how did you come up with the range (97-123)?

Comment: thats the acsii values to generate the list of the alphabet characters. [see here](https://theasciicode.com.ar/). ascii 97 = 'a', ascii 98 = 'b', and so on. So it's going from 97 to 122, which is 'a' to 'z'

Comment: I could have just done `['a','b','c','d',...]`. or `[abcd...]` and iterate through those.

Comment: @dwebb, i just realized you said in the OP you want a-w? If thats the case, just change the range to 97-120

Comment: Interesting approach using the character map.  I will remember this approach and likely use it somewhere myself.  Definitely gets an upvote from me.

Comment: when i run the code, the code runs for a couple of lines then i get this error :address = soup.find('p',{'class':'spk street-address'}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text. what could be the problem?

Comment: ok. that means theres no address. you can use a `try/except` to catch and/or pass the error. I'll edit the solution above

Comment: i am humbly asking you to show me how to insert the try/except to the above code.

Comment: @dwebb, yup! check the solution for the edit. It's sort of like `if / then` statement, but rather the `if` part is saying `if no error` do this, `else` do that

Comment: @chitown88: it now runs perfectly. Thank you, i appreciate.